# Spoofing MAC address in a persistent fashion

Tags: mac-address

So I like to set a new, randomly-generated MAC address after every restart using

`ruby -e 'print ("%02x"%((rand 64)*4|2))+(0..4).inject(""){|s,x|s+":%02x"%(rand 256)} + "\n"'`

and then copy/pasting the output after the command

`sudo ifconfig en0 ether`

so that I get a new IP address from my ISP each day. I would like to further automate this process so that on startup my computer automatically runs these two commands, but I don't know enough about CLI syntax to make it work. How can I combine these two commands so that `ifconfig` takes the generated output of the `ruby` command in a single step? And then, how can I get that to automatically run at startup?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `EDITOR=nano sudo crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`@reboot ifconfig en0 ether $(printf \%02x $(($RANDOM\%128*2)))$(head -c4 /dev/random|hexdump -v -e '/1 ":\%02x"')`

Commands scheduled by `@reboot` are run after you restart or turn the computer on but not after you log out and back in. `%` has to be escaped as `\%` in crontab.

From a comment at http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/10/random-mac-address-generator/:

> You need to be careful that this does not generate multicast mac addresses, as these are technically illegal as source macs. The strict definition of a multicast mac address is one where the least significant bit of the first byte is set to 1. So if the first octet’s LSB is 1 (01, 03,05, a1, etc) you technically have a multicast mac source. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address.
>
> Using multicast src macs might not cause immediate connectivity problems, but certainly has implications for switches learning the mac address preventing unicast flooding, and routers allowing arp to resolve.
>
> Cisco, for example, will not allow mac learning if the source is non-unicast, and Cisco routers will not install arp entries for multicast macs to unicast ip addresses.

Comment: I was aware of the multicast issue from the osxdaily link; I believe the `ruby` code I was using accounted for this. I'm still trying to reverse-engineer the syntax you're using to figure out the general case for how to "embed" one command inside another.

Comment: The ruby command you included does also account for it, but I just added the quote as an explanation why the command used `$(($RANDOM%128*2))`. A third option would be `ruby -e 'puts ([rand(128)*2]+(1..4).map{|x|rand(256)}).map{|x|x.to_s(16)}*":"'`. You can use command substitution `$()` to embed commands.

Comment: Thanks. Where is `crontab` supposed to be saved in OS X? After doing ^O to save changes, `nano` puts it in /tmp/crontab.jqR7fMrDDo.save which I'm not sure is going to work after a restart (I'm not in a position to be able to restart yet).

Comment: The crontab of the root user is stored in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs/root`, but you're not supposed to edit it directly.